# How to hide/show list columns in SharePoint Online using a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, list, workflow

I have a List form which is divided into 3 part. Sales, Purchasing and AP. I want a functionality through workflow (or a way around if its not possible) where after the sales fields are filled, the form is saved and the workflow is triggered and the purchasing part is active and now people from purchasing can fill their fields and so on.

What is the best way of achieving this? I can build a normal workflow myself but I do not know how to hide and show the fields.

I don't want to use InfoPath forms. I have built a simple list form but this new specification has me puzzled. Is it possible to do in a list form ?

**EDIT:** I know that individual security on List columns is not possible. So do I need to divide the form in 3 parts and hide/show the parts using a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use InfoPath forms, but I customised the form using InfoPath if that makes sense.

So basically you are still using the Newifs.aspx, and editifs.aspx but if you edit *using* InfoPath (not making an InfoPath form) you will be able to have 3 different page views that can be switched based on criteria on the form.

So, go to your list > Select Customise form on the ribbon > and then create your views - 1 for initial creation, 1 for purchasing and 1 for AP. Once you've done that, you need to build rules as to how the form will know what view to switch to.

For a walk through, try this > https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-89677734-2a77-47fa-8c04-d83fd24f18c2